# Автозаполнение полей формы авторизированного пользователя Django

Tags: python, django

Нужна помощь. Подскажите плиз. Есть форма для заказа товара. Нужно сделать так чтобы авторизированный пользователь при переходе к форме заказа, видел сразу заполненную форму его данными из профиля с возможностью эти данные отредактировать. Если пользоаптель не залогинин то просто открывалась пустая форма.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from orders.models import Order


class NewOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone',
                  'email', 'city', 'postal_code']
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from orders.models import OrderProducts, Order
from cart.cart import Cart
from orders.forms import NewOrderForm


def new_order(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewOrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderProducts.objects.create(order=order,
                                             product=item['product'],
                                             price=item['price'],
                                             quantity=item['quantity'])
            cart.clear()
            order_id = OrderProducts.objects.last()
            return render(request, 'orders/order/created_order.html', {'order_id': order_id})
    else:
        form = NewOrderForm()
    return render(request, 'orders/order/new_order.html', {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

new_order.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
  New order
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>New order</h1>
    <form action="." method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
      {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
  <div>
    <h3>Your order</h3>
    <ul>
      {% for item in cart %}
        <li>
          {{ item.product.title }} X {{ item.quantity }}
          <span>{{ item.total_price }}</span>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <p>Total: ${{ cart.get_total_price }}</p>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth_day = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='account/users_photo/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У формы есть такой параметр как initial, который отвечает за исходное значение в поле

```py
form = NewOrderForm(initial={'email': request.user.email})
```

Comment: Спасибо, изначально капал этот метод, но как оказалось не правильно писал логику обработчика.